# Combine subversion file history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We use subversion (with TortoiseSVN) to manage our source code, and generally it works well for us.  However, we just discovered that a month or so ago, the new hire accidentally moved some files and committed them without preserving the history (i.e. they were added as new, not moved).  We've been happily making changes to the files since, without noticing their new location.  Now I want to move these files back to their original location, while preserving both the changes we've made in the last month and the history of these files before the accidental move.

Is that possible?  Everything I've tried has given me the history of either the original or the copy, never both combined.  There were no changes to the original file after the copy was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. However, it is some work and it is not perfect.

Let's assume only one file was moved, and it happened in rev 42. Create a feature branch right before it happened:

```
svn cp ^/trunk@41 ^/branches/fix
```

Go to the feature branch, merge the bad rev 42 and fix the move before committing:

```
svn switch ^/branches/fix
svn merge -c 42 ^/trunk
svn revert foo.txt bar.txt
svn mv foo.txt bar.txt
svn commit
```

Verify the results. The following command should show only changes for the property `svn:mergeinfo`:

```
svn diff ^/trunk@42 ^/branches/fix
```

Sync merge all other changes from the trunk:

```
svn merge ^/trunk
svn commit
```

Reintegrate the branch into the trunk:

```
svn switch ^/trunk
svn merge --reintegrate ^/branches/fix
```

The file `bar.txt` now contains the whole history. Although the revisions since 42 are only shown with the option `-g` (`--use-merge-history`).

Comment: I finally had a chance to try this - it's a huge pain to do, but it worked.  `^` needs to be `^^` (or otherwise escaped) on Windows, though.  Took me a bit to figure that out.